# Preview content on website linking to full page, SEO strikes for duplicate content?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do search engines treat index pages with excerpts as duplicate content of the pages they link to?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8758/do-search-engines-treat-index-pages-with-excerpts-as-duplicate-content-of-the-pa)

I have a press section on a website i'm developing. It has about 10 press releases with truncated text from the full press release. There is a link to the full page that has the full press release.

My question is, will having the preview page of content hurt my SEO because of duplicate content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be an issue. Duplicate content becomes an issue when two URLs pull up the same content. Having summaries of other pages' content isn't doing this. In fact, this is how most WordPress blogs are set up and they do just find in the search results.